# enhanced write filter api c#

Tags: c#, api

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and coding in c#.

```
 public partial class App : Application
    {
    [DllImport("ewfapi.dll")]   
    public static extern IntPtr EwfMgrOpenProtected(string lpVolume);
    [DllImport("ewfapi.dll")]   
     public static extern bool EwfMgrCommit(IntPtr hDevice);


 public static bool EWFcommit()
    {
     temp = true;

        string strVolumeName = "C:";


        hProVol = EwfMgrOpenProtected(strVolumeName);       
       temp = EwfMgrCommit(hProVol);

       return temp;
}
}
```

The problem I'm having is that these commands do not work on the machine with the EWF enabled.
I've attempted to get the Volume Name from ewfmanager instead of hardcoding it to "C:".  However, I'm still learning and I'm having trouble using the command "EwfMgrGetProtectedVolumeList".  This api command will return the VolumeName I need to run the other ewfapi commands.  However, this command returns "PEWF_VOLUME_NAME_ENTRY " variable which I need to define.  This is where I get stuck.
In C++, the header file defines this variable, but in c# header files are non existent.  Would I have to convert  C++ code to c# code in order to use structures defined in the header file?
Currently, I'm using a work around by executing the commands via command prompt which works flawlessly.  But, I'm curious and want to learn the "right"/best way to do this in c#.
Please let me know of any experience using api commands in C#. Thank you.

This is the code I'm trying to convert to C#. I'm unsure how to convert the Declarators in C++ to C#.

```
 typedef struct _EWF_VOLUME_NAME_ENTRY
 {
struct _EWF_VOLUME_NAME_ENTRY* Next;
 WCHAR Name[1];
 } EWF_VOLUME_NAME_ENTRY, * PEWF_VOLUME_NAME_ENTRY;
```

This is the converted C# code without the declarators:

```
 public struct EWF_VOLUME_NAME_ENTRY
    {

        /// _EWF_VOLUME_NAME_ENTRY*
        public System.IntPtr Next;

        /// WCHAR[1]
         public string Name;
    }
```

Comment: "Would I have to convert C++ code to c# code in order to use structures defined in the header file?", yes you do. [Whole sites](http://pinvoke.net/) are devoted to this (I checked, did not see `ewfapi.dll`).

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the link to a great site though!

Comment: If you add the code from the C++ header file someone might be able to help you translate it to C#.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt was actually really close, it just needed some attributes to help the compiler along (in fact it may have worked without them)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct EWF_VOLUME_NAME_ENTRY 
{    
    /// _EWF_VOLUME_NAME_ENTRY*
    public System.IntPtr Next;

    /// WCHAR[1]    
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=1)]
    public string Name;
}
```

To use it, the P/Invoke signature of your method would be.

```
[DllImport("ewfapi.dll")]   
public static extern IntPtr EwfMgrGetProtectedVolumeList();
```

You also need a few more functions

```
[DllImport("ewfapi.dll")]   
public static extern void EwfMgrVolumeNameListDelete(IntPtr list);
[DllImport("ewfapi.dll")]   
public static extern bool EwfMgrVolumeNameListIsEmpty(IntPtr list);
[DllImport("ewfapi.dll")]   
public static extern void EwfMgrVolumeNameEntryPop(ref IntPtr list);
```

You could then get the list of protected volumes like so.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetProtectedVolumeNames()
{
    var listptr = EwfMgrGetProtectedVolumeList();
    if(listptr == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new Win32Exception(); //the default constuctor calls Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() for you.

    try
    {
        while(!EwfMgrVolumeNameListIsEmpty(listPtr))
        {
            var currentStruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure<EWF_VOLUME_NAME_ENTRY>(listPtr); 

            // Pre .NET 4.5.1 version
            // var currentStruct = (EWF_VOLUME_NAME_ENTRY)Marshal.PtrToStructure(listPtr, typeof(EWF_VOLUME_NAME_ENTRY));

            yield return currentStruct.Name;
            EwfMgrVolumeNameEntryPop(ref listPtr);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if(listptr != IntPtr.Zero)
            EwfMgrVolumeNameListDelete(listptr);
    }
}
```

Note this code was written in the browser and is untested, but I think it should work.

EDIT: Important note, if you use this function outside of a `foreach` and instead manually go through the `IEnumerable` be sure to dispose of it, otherwise the finally block will not execute and you will have a memory leak (a `foreach` automatically calls dispose for you when you leave the scope of the loop).

---

On a side note you may want to check out this old MSDN Magazine article: "[Making PInvoke Easy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/03/14/making-pinvoke-easy.aspx)". It includes a link to a program that you can give it the C/C++ signature and it will give you back a rough version of the .NET P/Invoke signature.

Answer (score 0):

Minor tweak to Scotts answer.  The name is a null terminated string, so increase the SizeConst to get the rest of the characters of the name:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct EWF_VOLUME_NAME_ENTRY 
{    
    /// _EWF_VOLUME_NAME_ENTRY*
    public System.IntPtr Next;

    /// WCHAR[1]    
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=300)]
    public string Name;
}
```